# TreeNode Remove() not working

Tags: c#, winforms, tree, treeview

Long story short:

- I traverse a generic tree and collect some nodes to a list according to a filter
- after a complete traversal I start removing each node one by one

remove collected nodes

```
foreach (TreeData nd in nodeBucket.Reverse<TreeData>())
{
    if (nd.node.Parent != null)
    {
        nd.node.Remove();
    }
}
```

The tree has about 2000 nodes. Somehow when all nodes should be deleted there are a couple of nodes that don't get removed, Remove() is called upon them and they have a null parent afterwords.  The nodes that don't get deleted are always the same.

Also tried `node.Parent.Nodes.Remove(node)`, no luck.

```
tree.BeginUpdate();
tree.EndUpdate();
tree.Invalidate();
tree.Refresh();
tree.Update();
```

not working.

TreeData struct looks like this:

```
struct TreeData
{
    public TreeData( TreeNode node) 
    {
        this.node   = node;
        this.parent = node.Parent;
        this.level  = node.Level;
    }

    public TreeNode node;
    public TreeNode parent;
    public int level; 
}
```

**Issue fixed**: the problem was related to duplicate nodes (the filtering was checking node names).

Comment: What do you mean by "don't get removed"? Do they remain in the Nodes collection of their parent node?

Comment: They are displayed/visible in the treeview even though after they get removed they will have the Parent reference set to null and the parent node will have no reference to them.

Comment: So you have traverse code, can you update the question with that also

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the current node but only need to remove the children

```
While(node.Nodes.Count>0)
   node.Nodes[0].Remove();
```